# Add a hi-res download link to image

Tags: jquery

I have a series of images with alt tag as captions, I am trying to insert after an download link that swaps ny1.jpg with ny1_hires.jpg

```
<img src="img/ny1.jpg" alt="Lunar New Year 2012: Year of the Dragon" />
<img src="img/ny2.jpg" alt="An 18 meter long dragon at Malang city park" />
<img src="img/ny3.jpg" alt="Actors perform the dragon dance" />
```

And I am wraping and displaying the caption with this:

```
$(".press img").each(function () {
var imageCaption = $(this).attr("alt");
var downloadLink = $(this).prop("src");
$(this).wrap("<div class='download'></div>");
if (imageCaption != '') {
    $("<span class='img-caption'><em>" + imageCaption + "</em><em> <a href=" + downloadLink + ">Download</a></em></span>")
        .insertAfter(this);
}

});
```

Right now this just inserts `<a href="/ny1.jpg">Download</a>`

Any help would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. You have to replace `img` `src` value using [`.split().`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) Try this:

```
$(".press img").each(function () {
var imageCaption = $(this).attr("alt");
var downloadLink = $(this).prop("src").split(".jpg")[0]+"_hires.jpg"; // split and add _hires.jpg
$(this).wrap("<div class='download'></div>");
if (imageCaption != '') {
    $("<span class='img-caption'><em>" + imageCaption + "</em><em> <a href=" + downloadLink + ">Download</a></em></span>")
        .insertAfter(this);
}
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/zbvhA/)**

Comment: Perfect! Yes I need to remember the split! thank you!! Will accept in a sec

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
// Change this:
var downloadLink = $(this).prop("src");
// To this:
var downloadLink = $(this).prop("src")
  .replace(".jpg", "_hires.jpg")
  .replace(".png", "_hires.png");
```